# How to send an email to all members of a Drupal Group when new content is created?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-rules

I've watched the tutorial about "[Drupal 8 Group Module Overview](https://youtu.be/GkiCLJk5n0s)". I have now a Drupal site running that uses the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.

I want to create the feature that sends emails to members once a new content is published. I also found the question "[How to email all group members after a new node is added when using the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/170910/39516)", but it does not contain any actual implementation.

Has anyone succeeded with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) integration?

Comment: That question appears to contain a fairly detailed walk through. You might looks at a more general rules tutorial to help you understand how to create a rule.

Comment: @acrosman : merci (thank you) for the kudos (i think your "*that question*" refers to the answer linked in the question details ...). Looks like I might post "an" answer specific to this question also ... some day ... If anybody is in a hurry: a bounty might speed up things ...